# How to make manipulation input type date in PHP and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, date, calendar

I'm developing appointment system with PHP. I want to make manipulation on input date calendar.
So if a client wants to create appointment, client will select the desired day/month/year.

When a different client wants to create appointment, selected fields so other day/month/year will be display disabled. How can i do this. Do you have anyone idea?

If you can show simple example, i will be very happy.

Thanks, regards.

Comment: what you mean by When a different client wants to create appointment, selected fields so other day/month/year will be display disabled?

Comment: Are you saying if someone has already that appointment, others should not be able to select that date?

Comment: Yes! Absolutely. Can you help me?

Comment: i will make first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use out focus or blur method so that you can disable the previous date from selecting.
for eg. 
if client selected date   = 25/12/2019

if another client selected the same date then

```
$('input').blur(function(){
  if($('client_2_selected_date').val() == client_1_selected_date){
     alert("date matched please select another date");
     $('client_2_selected_date').val("")
  }
else{
  alert("different date")
}
})
```